# How to update both Email and Password with new Firebase in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing app with new firebase from google.
And I'm having problem with updating user email and password.

Here's what I've tried.

```
let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

currentUser?.updateEmail(email) { error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)

    } else {
        // Email updated.
        currentUser?.updatePassword(password) { error in
            if let error = error {

            } else {
                // Password updated.
                print("success")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when updating password this occurs error like this.

> "Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17014 "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication..."

As I know we have to re-configure user after updating email.

I tried with this code for re-cofiguring from the firebase.

```
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
var credential: FIRAuthCredential

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials

user?.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential) { error in
  if let error = error {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // User re-authenticated.
  }
}
```

But this occurs error

> Variable 'credential' used before being initialed

I know this is because I don't initialize 'credential' variable but I don't know how to fix this to work.

Is there anybody who knows solution?

Comment: It works for me after I log in. I can change the email and password this way.

Comment: Hi, @EICaptainv2.0 I've updated my answer, Could you please have a look and give me solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your edit you didn't initialize your `FIRAuthCredential` ... it should be `var credential = FIRAuthCredential()` or simply use it like below code

```
let credential = FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider.credentialWithEmail(email, password: password)

user?.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential) { error in
   if let error = error {
       // An error happened.
   } else {
      // User re-authenticated.
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hello can you suggestion me i have to update email not password thank you

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133637/updating-email-to-firebase 

2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users
@YogeshPatel

Comment: Hello, i tried this  but it not update email address it save new entry with users/uid in realtime database i want to update authenticate email address please check this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54958026/how-to-update-only-email-address-in-firebase-authentication-for-ios-swift-4