# Updating Email to firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

It prints CHANGED in my console but nothing is changing and the users email is remaining the same. The placeholder texts reverts back to the original email and my Firebase Database for email for that specific user is also unchanged. I want to allow the user to have the option to change any part of their profile including email, password, location, and other values they stored when first signing up. In order to do this will I have to log them out and have them resign in? That would seem to be a terrible user experience.

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var location: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var updateEmail: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var updateLocation: UIButton!
@IBAction func updateEmailAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser

    currentUser?.updateEmail(to: email.text!) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)  
        } else {
            print("CHANGED") 
        }
    }
}

var dataBaseRef: DatabaseReference! {
    return Database.database().reference()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userRef = dataBaseRef.child("users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")

    userRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let user = Users(snapshot: snapshot)

        if let email = user.email{
            self.email.placeholder = email  
        }

        if let location = user.location{
            self.location.placeholder = location
        }
    }  
)}
```

Comment: Maybe the auth email changes independently from the email in your snapshot. Even though you are changing the Auth email, you are not calling to change the email child in the database from where the snapshot comes

Comment: I will look into that, however the snapshot is only being used to set the placeholder text. The updateEmailAction function should be calling to change right into the database shouldn't it?

Comment: i think you're only changing the email the user uses to login. I don't know what your data structure looks like but it seems there should be a dataBaseRef.child("email").setValue(email.text) to change the dictionary value in the database itself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .updateEmail function updates the users email in their *Firebase credentials* and has nothing to do with what's stored in your /users node.

If you are keeping a duplicate email there, you would need to write that data to the /users/uid node when the .updateEmail function succeeds. i.e. the /users node is something *you* created, and is not maintained by Firebase.

```
@IBAction func updateEmailAction(_ sender: Any) {

   let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser

   currentUser?.updateEmail(to: email.text!) { error in
       if let error = error {
           print(error)  
       } else {
           print("CHANGED")
           let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
           let thisUserRef = fbRef.child("users").child(uid)
           let thisUserEmailRef = thisUserRef.child("email")
           thisUserEmailRef.setValue(email.text!) 
       }
   }
}
```